# How to stop the DOM until particular js file is loaded completely?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a DOM with lots of `script` files in that I have one file called `contact.js`. This file is responsible for the loading the contacts into the application. Now, I want to show a loader until that `contacts.js` loaded. And then I want to display the index page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the `contact.js` script is linked in your page's header, you can use jQuery's [document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event to make sure that all DOM elements and scripts were loaded.

So if you want to hide the page completely, you can set a loader DIV which will cover the entire page:

```
<div id='loader' style='height:100vh; width:100%; background-color:white'></div>
```

And then in the document ready event handler, you can hide this loader, making your page visible and ready for work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
});
```

Or the shorthand version:

```
$(function() {
    $('#loader').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/vLbbkcna/7/) for what you want to achieve.

You can achieve the same effect with `document.ready` and `.hide`. I used jQuery for the `fadeOut` animation.